# PHP: How to display only rows that have this value

Tags: php, html, laravel

Sorry for the question. I feel like it is a very simple answer, but I haven't had any luck researching. I am new to this. I am trying to make a website on Laravel. This webpage is supposed to show brothers in a chart. I only want brothers that are considered "good noodles". In the table there is a boolean value called `GoodNoodles` which is either 1 or 0. Here is my attempt to only show that:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody class="text-center">
        @foreach($brothers as $b)
            <tr>
                @if($b['GoodNoodle']="1")
                    <td><a class="link" href="#">{{$b->fName.' '.$b->lName}}</a></td>
                @endif
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It works fine when I take out the if statement, as it shows me all the brothers.

The problem is that I go on the website all the brothers show up even though some of them have 0 for their `GoodNoodle` value. I think that my problem is that I am not sure how to run this if statement. I am new to PHP.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I go on the website all the brothers show up even though some of them have 0 for their GoodNoodle value. I think that my problem is that I am not sure how to run this if statement. I am new to PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are **assigning** the value 1 to the GoodNoodle value of all brothers:

```
if($b['GoodNoodle']="1")
```

To **compare** values the if should be:

```
if ($b['GoodNoodle'] == "1")
```

But, if GoodNoodle is not numeric and it's a boolean I prefer doing:

```
if ($b['GoodNoodle'])
```

Finally, all this answers is assuming b is an array and GoodNoodle a key of this array. In case GoodNoodle is a property of the brother object the condition should be:

```
if ($b->GoodNoodle)
```

Comment: I upvoted, this is the answer, but you have a few inaccuracies which might confuse OP.  `if ($b['GoodNoodle'])` works here too, values are just 0 or 1. Also, we know `$b` is a model, at least based on the rest of the code.  And lastly, you probably meant "`$b` is an object" - $brothers appears to be a collection (or array).